# How can i escape properly double quotes in a razor view?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, razor

By using backslash i escape double quotes as such

```
Code @(model.Required == true ? "<span class=\"text-danger\"> *</span>" : "")
```

but unforunately the output rendered is

```
Code <span class="text-danger"> *</span>
```

instead of

```
Code *
```

where `*` denotes a required field...

How should i fix this one?

Comment: Try: `@Html.Raw(model.Required ? "<span class=\"text-danger\"> *</span>" : "")`

Comment: Or just plain `@if(model.Required) { <span class="required">*</span> }` which looks neater, is proper HTML and doesn't require the (sometimes dangerous) Html.Raw.

Comment: Ended up with the second option, do you mind posting it as an answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of ways to do this

1. Using `Html.Raw`:

   ```
   @Html.Raw(model.Required ? "<span class=\"text-danger\"> *</span>" : "")
   ```
2. Use a plain `if` statement:

   ```
   @if(model.Required) { <span class="required">*</span> }
   ```

   I prefer this as the content of the `if` statement is pure HTML code so doesn't require escaping the quotes, and it avoids using `Html.Raw` which can introduce security issues in your code.